# MySQL redundant foreginkeys

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have created `MySQL` database for my `Java` `Spring` project. I use `MySQL Workbench`. I have started creating EER diagrams. I have question about relationship between three tables. Why I get in system tables column `type_labels_id`? I think that is redundant foregin key because I can get labels_id from type table using just type_id in system table. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: When I'm creating relationship between two tables: `type` and `system`, MySQL creates `type_labels_id`. Why?

Comment: Well, mysql doesn't do anything by itself. It's not AI and it doesn't know anything about you, me or Santa. It does only thing that you tell it. So check your code that creates db and you will find answer there.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating a relationship its `type_lables_id` will generated my your references,You don't need to create a new column name `type_id`.If you need to  use this name as your foreign  key, simply rename the `type_labels_id`  to `type_id`